# GroupBy for a nested property with Pagination typeorm queryBuilder

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express, typeorm

Let's say i have items oneToOne with videoItems manyToMany with categories.
I would like to perform a query where i get all the items joined with videoItems divided by categories. In the same query i would like to perform pagination in the items.

This is the outPut like of my query.

```js
[
  { uuid: "uuid",
    videoItem: {
      uuid: "uuid"
      categories: [
        {
          uuid: "uuid",
          title: "string",
        }
        {
          uuid: "uuid",
          title: "string",
        }  
      ]
    }
]
```

I would like to produce an output like this:

```js
[
  (category 1)
  { uuid: "uuid",
    title: "string,
    items: [
    {
      uuid: "uuid"
      videoItem: 
        {
          uuid: "uuid",
        }
    }
     {
      uuid: "uuid"
      videoItem: 
        {
          uuid: "uuid",
        }
    }
   (category 2)
    ....
]
```